# DECLARE_COMPLETION_ONSTACK functionality in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, spi

Please can any one help me in understanding the difference between "DECLARE_COMPLETION_ONSTACK" and static(DECLARE_COMPLETION(comp)) or dynamic initialization?

I have found some reference like below(http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spidev.c#L110):

```
110 spidev_sync(struct spidev_data *spidev, struct spi_message *message)
111 {
112         DECLARE_COMPLETION_ONSTACK(done);
113         int status;
114 
115         message->complete = spidev_complete;
116         message->context = &done;
117 
118         spin_lock_irq(&spidev->spi_lock);
119         if (spidev->spi == NULL)
120                 status = -ESHUTDOWN;
121         else
122                 status = spi_async(spidev->spi, message);
123         spin_unlock_irq(&spidev->spi_lock);
124 
125         if (status == 0) {
126                 wait_for_completion(&done);
127                 status = message->status;
128                 if (status == 0)
129                         status = message->actual_length;
130         }
131         return status;
132 }
```

Looks like here its waiting till spi_sync() function gets completed,I have couple of queries in understanding above function

2:does it mean this function is not really concurrent?(as this completion variable imposes kind of serialization)

BR,
& Sridhar

Answer (score 0):

It has no difference if LOCK_DEP is not enabled.

It is only useful for lock debug functionalities.

See below kernel code,

```
47/*
48 * Lockdep needs to run a non-constant initializer for on-stack
49 * completions - so we use the _ONSTACK() variant for those that
50 * are on the kernel stack:
51 */

59#ifdef CONFIG_LOCKDEP
60# define DECLARE_COMPLETION_ONSTACK(work) \
61  struct completion work = COMPLETION_INITIALIZER_ONSTACK(work)
62#else
63# define DECLARE_COMPLETION_ONSTACK(work) DECLARE_COMPLETION(work)
64#endif
```